# Tic Tac Toe Javascript won't change players

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Tic Tac Toe</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        .Row {
            display:table-row;
        }
        .cell {
            display: table-cell;
            border: solid black;
            border-width: medium;
            padding: 0 3px;
            height: 95px;
            width: 95px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 40px;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        var xPlayer = prompt("Player x what is your name?");
        var oPlayer = prompt("Player o what is your name?");
        var currentPlayer = "X";
        var xGameTotal = 0;
        var oGameTotal = 0;
        var xWins = 0;
        var oWins = 0;
        var xMessage = 0;
        var oMessage = 0;
        var winsArray = [7, 56, 448, 73, 146, 292, 273, 84];

        function playerMoved(id,value){
            changeMarker(id);
            updatePlayerTotal(value);

            if (checkWinner(xGameTotal)){
                xWins ++;
                if (xWins ===1)
                {
                    xMessage = " time";
                }
                else
                {
                    xMessage = " times";
                }
                resetBoard();
            }
            if (checkWinner(oGameTotal)) {
                oWins ++;
                if (oWins ===1) 
                {
                    oMessage = " time";
                }
                else
                {
                    oMessage = " times";
                }
                resetBoard();
            }

            switchPlayers();
        }
        function changeMarker(box){
            if (currentPlayer === "X")
            {
                box.innerHTML = 'X';
            }
            else
            {
                box.innerHTML = 'O';
            }
        }
        function switchPlayers(){
            if (currentPlayer === "X")
            {
                currentPlayer = 'X';
            }
            else
            {
                currentPlayer = 'O';
            }
        }
        function updatePlayerTotal(score){
            if (currentPlayer === "X")
            {
                xGameTotal = xGameTotal + score;
            }
            else 
            {
                oGameTotal = oGameTotal + score;
            }
        }
        function checkWinner(score){
            for (var index = 0; index < winsArray.length; index += 1)
            {
                if ((winsArray[index] & score) === winsArray[index])
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }   
        function resetBoard(){
            var board = document.getElementsByClassName("cell");
            for (var i=0; i < board.length; i++){
                board[i].innerHTML="";
            }
            oGameTotal=0;
            xGameTotal=0;

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="start()">
    <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
    <div class="Row">
        <div class="cell" onClick="playerMoved(this,1)"></div>
        <div class="cell" onClick="playerMoved(this,2)"></div>
        <div class="cell" onClick="playerMoved(this,4)"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="Row">
        <div class="cell" onClick="playerMoved(this,8)"></div>
        <div class="cell" onClick="playerMoved(this,16)"></div>
        <div class="cell" onClick="playerMoved(this,32)"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="Row">
        <div class="cell" onClick="playerMoved(this,64)"></div>
        <div class="cell" onClick="playerMoved(this,128)"></div>
        <div class="cell" onClick="playerMoved(this,256)"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I can't get the player to switch. It's always player X when you click on the squares. What am I missing? I thought maybe my nesting was wrong but I can't seem to find anything. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your if condition (switchPlayers) is wrong. You are checking if the current play is x and then you set the current player to x again.

Just change these lines:

```
function switchPlayers(){
    if (currentPlayer === "X") {
        currentPlayer = 'X';
    } else {
        currentPlayer = 'O';
    }
}
```

to:

```
function switchPlayers(){
    if (currentPlayer === "X") {
        currentPlayer = 'O';
    } else {
        currentPlayer = 'X';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Making the edit that Tommy suggests fixes the issue for me!

If you want to make the code more succinct, you can also accomplish this in one line using [ternary operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), like so:

```
function switchPlayers() {
    currentPlayer = currentPlayer === 'X' ? 'O' : 'X';
}
```

You can use ternaries in other parts of your code, too, to help avoid repetitive `if else` statements, if you like.

Basically, you can replace:

```
if(a === 'b') {
    c = 'foo';
}
else {
    c = 'bar';
}
```

With: `c = a === 'b' ? 'foo' : 'bar'`.

Ternaries may seem a little confusing at first, but getting used to them can help prevent these sort of simple errors in the future, as a result of more succinct code.